# T-sql query to compute a new column from the existing cilumn

Tags: t-sql

I have a table as shown below

```
Dealid  comment           amount  swaplink  
A11     Nothing           1000    
B11     this is swaP1     2000
b22     this is swap2     3000
b33     this is swap1     4000
b44     this is swap2     5000
```

`Swaplink` is a computed column from comment we need to follow 4 steps to follow

1. whether "swap" is occuring in comment column
2. check the number after swap
3. find swap1 which is not in the samw row,repeat it for all rows
4. in swaplink put the dealids

Comment: Show us the DDL of table and try to make your question more readable and understandable

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you - you cannot create persisted or indexable computed column on the table which relates any other rows, else you can use User Defined Function to encapsulate your logic, but you should understand that it will be performance killer.

If you need not the column in the table, but just a column in the query - you still may use your UDF or write your own subqueries

To make your life a little bit easier for yourself - try to separate swap2 and similar values into 2 columns with values swan AND 2